# Count combination factors and inverse of them simultaneously

Tags: r, count

I have a dataframe with 2 columns of factors variables like this:

```
V1 <- c("A","B","C","Y","D","E","F","U","G","H","I","J","R")
V2 <- c("Z","Y","W","B","V","U","T","E","S","R","Q","P","H")
df <- cbind(V1,V2)
df
 V1  V2 
[1,] "A" "Z"
[2,] "B" "Y"
[3,] "C" "W"
[4,] "Y" "B"
[5,] "D" "V"
[6,] "E" "U"
[7,] "F" "T"
[8,] "U" "E"
[9,] "G" "S"
[10,] "H" "R"
[11,] "I" "Q"
[12,] "J" "P"
[13,] "R" "H"
```

Now I woudl like to count, using a function, all the cases where the combination of V1 and V2 equals to combination V2 and V1 and return them, for example for df this count will be equal to 3, like this:

```
 y <-combinations_inver(df[,1],df[,2])

 y$Combinations
 "B""Y"= "Y""B"
 "E""U"= "U""E"
 "H""R"= "R""H"

 y$Count
[1] 3 #because there are three ocurrences (see $Combinations)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be:

```
forwards<-paste(V1,V2)
backwards<-paste(V2,V1)
```

The intersection of these two "sets" would be what you are looking for, but R gives both sets of matches, so you would need to divide the length by 2:

```
length(intersect(forwards, backwards))/2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmin` and `pmax` to reorder the elements for each row, then use `duplicated` to find the index of duplicate elements, get the `unique` rows after subsetting and get the `nrow`

```
m1 <- cbind(pmin(df[,1], df[,2]), pmax(df[,1], df[,2]))
i1 <- duplicated(m1)|duplicated(m1, fromLast=TRUE)
nrow(unique(m1[i1,]))
#[1] 3
```